# want to make 'X Post' request every N seconds with Nodejs ( i'm working on facebook chatbot so i wanna make 250 Post Request every second )

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I would like to do the following

1. I want to make 250 Post request Every 1 Second.
2. When I use the benchmark to choose the best Module for Request, it shows that superAgent is the fastest one to solve slow time request
   but still have this problem.

Will the following code help me to do that?

1 - **iterate though users**

2- **Push requests to myRequests Array**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  //console.log(i);
  myRequests.push(function(callback) {
    request.get(
      "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
      {
        qs: {
          access_token: "55"
        },
        json: {
          recipient: {
            id: users[i]
          },
          message: "55"
        }
      },
      (err, res) => {
        callback(null);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

`

3- **Set ParallelLimit to 250**

```
async.parallelLimit(
    myRequests, 250, function(err, results) {
});
```

`

Comment: `request.get`... i thought that you want to do post requests, not get requests? and why "every second"? what´s the use case for this?

Comment: yes , post request sorry : i want to make message to 1M users by 300 users/second so i want 300 request / second

Comment: i know that you want to send a lot of requests per seconds, but WHY exactly? this does sound very spammy.

Comment: as i mentioned before to deal with facebook chatbot broadcast but the following comment give me vary useful broadcast API from Facebook

Comment: oh, alright, so your problem is just to reach all your users, but not to send them countless messages, right?

Comment: yes , within short time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowest part is most likely the request to Facebook, no matter if you use superagent, axios or something else. If you want to broadcast messages, better use the Broadcast API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/broadcast-api/

Comment: you are welcome, please don´t forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: did you know what benefits from making Broadcast Schedule in Facebook Side other than my Server side ? also when i'm try Normal BroadCast message takes more than 3h why ?

Comment: i would assume that it´s a LOT faster that way, and you may hit api limits if you try to do that on your own. what do you mean with 3h? your own solution? either way, messages are not meant to be realtime anyway.